# How to sync to Rinkeby Test Network using geth in Windows?

Tags: go-ethereum, rinkeby, geth-debugging

Should I run this command or the ipcpath must be changed for Windows.

```
geth --rinkeby --rpc --rpcapi="personal,eth,network,web3,net" --ipcpath "~/Library/Ethereum/geth.ipc"
```

And after that what path should I specify in geth attach command?

Comment: I have a same problem. Does it solved? What is **ipcpath** on windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameter `--ipcpath` has different meaning on UNIX (e.g. on MacOS) and on Windows.  On UNIX it refers to local socket located somewhere in file system.  For windows it refers to named pipes, and named pipes reside in their own namespace, not in the file system.  Each named pipe has a name, but not path.  So, on Windows you may either omit this parameter so geth will use default value `geth.ipc`, or set something like this: `--ipcpath geth-rinkeby.ipc`.

Then you will need to use something like `geth attach ipc:\\.\pipe\geth-rinkeby.ipc` in order to attach to your node via this named pipe.

Comment: And what should  I add after geth attach, The command gives error: Unable to attach to remote geth: no known transport for URL scheme "c"